# Can I create a loop for 4 different drop lists?

Tags: javascript

In spite of this code actually working, I am trying to slim it down to a loop...So far all my attempts have failed. What you will see are four drop lists with different Id's...However, they do have the same class name `(optionLinks)`.
Here is the code:

```
function init(){

    var allE = document.getElementById("executive");
    allE.onchange = loadLink;

    var allL = document.getElementById("legislative");
    allL.onchange = loadLink;

    var allJ = document.getElementById("judicial");
    allJ.onchange = loadLink;

    var allS = document.getElementById("state");
    allS.onchange = loadLink;
}
```

Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 1):

With a moderately up-to-date browser:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.optionLinks'), function(a){
    a.addEventListener('change', loadLink);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/RrZYJ/).

References:

- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll).
- [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

Answer (score 0):

```
var ids = ['executive','legislative','judicial','state'];
for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++)
    document.getElementById(ids[i]).onChange = loadLink;
```

Or...

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('optionLinks');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
    elements[i].onChange = loadLink;
```

Comment: No need for an id list since they all have the optionLinks class.

Answer (score 0):

```
elements = document.getElementsByClassName('optionLinks');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].onchange = loadLink;
}
```

Comment: I suggest assigning `document.getElementsByClassName('optionLinks')` to a variable before the loop. The performance gain is negligible, but readability goes up a bit.

Comment: @Jeffman Good idea. (tho I'm usually to lazy to do it myself)

Comment: Question: my goal was to avoid an actual array(), but I tried optionLinks and it did not work. I was confused when to use brackets and when to use parenthesis...reply please :)

Comment: @erwade "it did not work" What happened? Sry for the late reply.